# What are good resources for a backend developer wanting to learn client-side programming in the browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, scripting, client-side

I want to learn how to write the Javascript/CSS/HTML side of my applications but I want to skip the CSS kludges, bad Javascript, and non-semanitic HTML of the past and jump directly to HTML 5, CSS 3, clean Javascript libraries. I've been reading Mark Pilgrim's [Dive In HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) which I think is awesome and now I'd like the equivilent books (or blog posts) for Javascript and CSS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my recommendations exactly in the same order. The first 3 books are very light reads & are sufficient enough to get started with client side programming. However, learning JQuery will make your Javascript development much easier. It is similar to learning to use regular expressions (but JQuery offers more than regex).

1. [Learning Web Design: A Beginner's Guide to (X)HTML, StyleSheets, and Web Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527527)
2. [Bulletproof Web Design: Improving flexibility and protecting against worst-case scenarios with XHTML and CSS (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)
3. [DOM Scripting: Web Design with JavaScript and the Document Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595335)
4. [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355)

Answer (score 3):

[`Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) is a classic.

Answer (score 1):

Learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) :o)

Comment: That wasn't quite the answer I was looking for. :-) I know of JQuery and the various other javascript libraries, but (out of ignorance) I assume that JQuery is part of that past that I want to skip. I really don't want to do a lot of stuff in the browser, I just want to do enough to make my site have teh snappy. I really just want an book titled: "How to add teh snappy to your website with HTML 5, CSS 3 and, a little itty bit of cleanly written Javascript".

Comment: No, you really want to use jQuery for that. It takes the pain out or writing small bits of JS that work cross-browser.

Comment: I agree with Devin; jQuery takes a terrible API (the DOM) with inconsistent implementations (browsers) and makes it fun to work with. Additionally, you may want to look at Prototype, a framework with a different approach than jQuery: it extends JavaScript's scripting-type functionality rather than it's implementation of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is an excellent site for a quick and simple start.

Comment: I've been there many times in the past but I can't get over how horribly designed the site is. There's so much going on on each page and so little actual information that I tend to give up. I expect a lot more from a site that is supposedly to teach me web development. Somebody should send those guys a Tufte book. Sorry for my snarky reply.

Comment: Also, the quality of code and advice on w3schools is quite variable, ranging from passable down to outright bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for object oriented javascript.  Douglas Crockford is a good author on the subject, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stomach the sometimes abrasive tone, try the [comp.lang.javascript Usenet group](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/topics). The archive is full of every JavaScript question or discussion you could imagine, and there are some seriously knowledgeable people on there.

Comment: Don't forget the spam. There is a hell of that to stomach on Usenet these days.

Answer (score -2):

I have to say learn JQuery and use Wordpress

Wordpress is way more than just a blog tool now and being able to code great XHTML / JQuery and be a wizard in CSS should cover everything.

Good luck :)